# only single or multiple occurrences records using inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've following query.

```
select 
dsccnf.Id cnfRptClmId,dsccnf.tblRptcatId cnfRptcatId,dsccnf.Category cnfCategory,
dsccnf.ClmNumber cnfNumber,dsccnf.State cnfState
from tblClmPeriod dcp 
inner join tblRptClm dsccnf on dsccnf.tblClmPeriodId = dcp.Id and dsccnf.State=3 --and dsccnf.tblClmPeriodId = 10288

|cnfRptClmId|cnfRptcatId|cnfCategory|cnfNumber|cnfState
|21341      |1650       |L2         |A        | 3
|21343      |1652       |L2         |A        | 3
|21345      |1657       |T1         |A        | 3
|21347      |1660       |T2         |B        | 3
|21356      |1670       |T1         |A        | 3
```

Getting above data, Now I only want to get all the items (cnfRptClmId,cnfCategory|cnfNumber|cnfState) 
a)  one type or single type Category plus ClmNumber columns (T2|B) i.e (|21347|1660|T2|B|   3) and similar records

b)  all the records occurring only two times and ignoring the rest i.e

```
|21341|1650|L2|A|3
|21343|1652|L2|A|3
|21345|1657|T1|A|3
|21356|1670|T1|A|3
```

I can afford two separate queries for both of these results. Thank in advance.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        dsccnf.Id cnfRptClmId,
        dsccnf.tblRptcatId cnfRptcatId,
        dsccnf.Category cnfCategory,
        dsccnf.ClmNumber cnfNumber,
        dsccnf.State cnfState,
        COUNT(dsccnf.Category) OVER (PARTITION BY dsccnf.Category) categoryCount
    FROM
        tblClmPeriod dcp
        INNER JOIN tblRptClm dsccnf ON dsccnf.tblClmPeriodId = dcp.Id
                                       AND dsccnf.State = 3
)
WHERE categoryCount = 2
```

`COUNT(dsccnf.Category) OVER (PARTITION BY dsccnf.Category)` will give you the count for that `dsccnf.Category` on every row, so you just wrap that in a subquery and select only the records that have a category count = 2

based on the comment below.. you can add another count for dsccnf.Category and dsccnf.ClmNumber, then check that count if you want to filter by it.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        dsccnf.Id cnfRptClmId,
        dsccnf.tblRptcatId cnfRptcatId,
        dsccnf.Category cnfCategory,
        dsccnf.ClmNumber cnfNumber,
        dsccnf.State cnfState,
        COUNT(dsccnf.Category) OVER (PARTITION BY dsccnf.Category) categoryCount,
        COUNT(dsccnf.Category) OVER (PARTITION BY dsccnf.Category, dsccnf.ClmNumber) categoryClmCount
    FROM
        tblClmPeriod dcp
        INNER JOIN tblRptClm dsccnf ON dsccnf.tblClmPeriodId = dcp.Id
                                       AND dsccnf.State = 3
)
WHERE categoryCount = 2 -- where category appears twice
      OR categoryClmCount = 1 -- where category/clm appear only once
```

Comment: how can we do it for for Category plus ClmNumber  please, any idea

Comment: the PARTITION BY determines how the COUNT is calculated.. if you want the count of dsccnf.Category, dsccnf.ClmNumber combinations then use `COUNT(dsccnf.Category) OVER (PARTITION BY dsccnf.Category, dsccnf.ClmNumber)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
    dsccnf.Id          cnfRptClmId,
    dsccnf.tblRptcatId cnfRptcatId,
    dsccnf.Category    cnfCategory,
    dsccnf.ClmNumber   cnfNumber,
    dsccnf.State       cnfState
from tblClmPeriod dcp 
inner join tblRptClm dsccnf on dsccnf.tblClmPeriodId = dcp.Id
                           and dsccnf.State=3
group by
    dsccnf.Id,
    dsccnf.tblRptcatId,
    dsccnf.Category,
    dsccnf.ClmNumber,
    dsccnf.State
having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: this seems to be the easiest of all but I'm not able to actually run it. I tried changing columns and got these error message. 

Column 'dsccnf.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @afr0: The column lists in the SELECT and GROUP BY clauses must be identical (except for omitting the aliases from the GROUP BY).